# Netsuite SCA: How to pass javascript variables in function netsuite?

Tags: javascript, ajax, netsuite

I have a JavaScript code  variable:

```
 jsVar = response;
```

and i need to insert this value into

```
 <%= displayInRows(jsVar, cellWrap) %>
```

How can i do?

I'm programming in Netsuite ambient, in particular SCA.

Thanks